# How to replace the value of element which is not found in another array in ascending order?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
let newer   = [7,8,10,0,2,3,9,24,1,4,20,19,23,5,21,6,22];

let indices_2=  [3,5,0,1,4,6,7,10,**13**,**16**,8,2,9,**14**,**15**,**11**,**12**];

Output should be = [3,5,0,1,4,6,7,10,**21**,**24**,8,2,9,**22**,**23**,**19**,**20**];
```

Hi guys, this might be tough. If the element in indices_2 is not found in newer, from smallest to largest value, lets say the **first smallest number** of indices_2 not found in newer is **11**, it is **replaced** by the **first smallest number** found in newer which is not found in indices_2 which is **19**. Then the sequence continues on for the the **second smallest number** of indices_2 not found in newer.

```js
let newer=[7,8,10,0,2,3,9,24,1,4,20,19,23,5,21,6,22];
  let indices_2=[3,5,0,1,4,6,7,10,13,16,8,2,9,14,15,11,12];
  let status_indices=[];  let status_indices_stat=[];
  for (let i=0;i<newer.length;i++){
    status_indices_stat="f"
    for (let f=0;f<newer.length;f++){
    if (indices_2[i]==newer[f]){
       status_indices_stat="t"
       //check whether element is found in newer.
     }

    }
    status_indices.push(status_indices_stat)
  }
  
  for (let f=0;f<newer.length;f++){
    if (status_indices[f]=="f"){
        for (let i=0;i<newer.length;i++){
         if (indices_2[f]<newer[i]){
           console.log(i)
         }
         
        }
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter both arrays with the opposite, sort them and take the array with filtered indices as pattern for the index of getting the value of the other filtered and sorted array.

```js
let newer = [7, 8, 10, 0, 2, 3, 9, 24, 1, 4, 20, 19, 23, 5, 21, 6, 22],
    indices2 = [3, 5, 0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 16, 8, 2, 9, 14, 15, 11, 12],
    temp1 = newer.filter(v => !indices2.includes(v)).sort((a, b) => a - b),
    temp2 = indices2.filter(v => !newer.includes(v)).sort((a, b) => a - b),
    result = indices2.map(v => newer.includes(v) ? v : temp1[temp2.indexOf(v)]);

console.log(...result);
```